# Ruby: Seaching a hash for something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the Highrise API and Ruby wrapper, but my problem is that (besides having a nightmare of a time with the API it self) I want to search a hash that is returned for something:

```
>> Highrise::Person.find(:all).detect{|p| p.name == 'Brandon'}
=> [#<Highrise::Person:0x102a4d2f8 @prefix_options={}, @attri....
```

I can do that but obviously `detect` along with using `==` will only return a single item and it must be an exact match, what if I want to search for something and it's not a complete match, more like it "contains" the value? Like take for example if I were to omit the "n" at the end of a name like so:

```
>> Highrise::Person.find(:all).detect{|p| p.name == 'Brando'}
=> nil
```

Obvously this would return `nil` but how would I have this return the items that contain "Brando" in the name?

Comment: May I suggest http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/index.html  -- looking through the methods of Hash which sound like they could select multiple items would have probably been faster than typing in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `select` to get all matching elements, also use regular expression instead of equality:

```
Highrise::Person.find(:all).select{|p| p.name =~ /Brando/i}
```

Answer (score 1):

Highrise::Person.find(:all).select{|p| p.name =~ /Brando/}

if you want multiple results.

the same block can be used  {|p| p.name =~ /Brando/ } with detect to get one element